# Can I "invert" a CSS transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here's what I would like to do:

It's a quiz, there's a question and several answers.
The user picks 1 answer and is then shown what the correct answer is.

I would like that the correct answer button "lights up" basically, and then fades back to normal.

So I can give my element a simple style and then add a class with a white box shadow.
And I can transition between the two.

But I'd like to add the class, and then the element gets the full white box shadow, which then fades back to the normal state.

Is that possible?

Comment: In short, yes. Have an attempt at it and ask specific questions where you come unstuck.

Comment: I might have miss understood, but maybe have a look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ 
This will allow you to 'animate' css transitions

Comment: @Widor Well I have built what I described.

And my problem is that the transition is only 2 steps.
It's either from lighted to normal or vice-versa.

I'd like to get the desired result without resorting to javascript or 3 different classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@keyframes` to do it in pure `CSS3`

```
@keyframes animation_name{
  0%   {background: color1;}
  50%  {background: color2;}
  100% {background: color1;}
}
```

and for the element where you want the animation

```
css_selector{
   animation: animation_name 5s;
   animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

and dont forget to add browser specific `-moz`, `-webkit` prefix.

Check out this Example on [w3schools on `CSS3 Animation`](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp)

Answer (score 0):

javascript apply class to element (no jquery):

document.getElementById("id").className = "newclass";

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QNCmu/) is a jsfiddle for you. Should do what you need - just click the black rectangle.